# How can I modify my question to get it "Wiki Approved"?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[Here is the post in question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6562/2422).

When I had originally asked this question I didn't think about adding it to the Wiki but as one commenter pointed out "Lists of information are discouraged".  After reviewing the FAQ I see his point but I still think my question is one that should be answered here on Android-SE.  Since users coming from iOS may come to the site seeking help I think the question is a good one but perhaps not in its current form.  So my question to meta is: How can I modify my question to be "Wiki Approved"? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very similar to a shopping recommendation and much of the same advice applies.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Beyond that, consider:

- you have created an "infinite list of X" question. Surely there is (probably) an Android equivalent for *every single iPhone app?*
- the equivalents, even if valid now, may change over time; apps change over time. The value of this list will be highly limited as it ages.

Perhaps if you had *specific* things you were looking for Android equivalents to on iPhone -- like the built in default applications. But scoping it to "any app that can ever be, or will ever be" just doesn't work.

Comment: I agree here. The question, as it stands, is too open-ended. We need specific apps (or, actually, problems to solve). Since *Angry Birds* is on Android, there's nothing the iPhone has that I want that I can't get on my Droid.

Comment: & @Al Thanks for you input.  I see what you mean. So should I just delete my post or vote to close it as well (it only needs one more)?

Comment: @dan ok, I closed it. Thanks for asking about this on meta -- that sets you apart from most other users, in a good way!